# How to Remove Textbox control created dynamically in WPF Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am unable to remove the textbox which is created Dynamically using Combobox selected Item in Grid. if the selected value is not equal to "Other (describe)", i have to remove the textbox. I have this code..

```
private void btn_addnew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ComboBox cmb=new ComboBox();
        .....
       cmb.SelectionChanged+= cmb_SelectionChanged;
       .....
    }


void cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var txt = new TextBox();
        if (e.AddedItems[0].ToString() == "Other (describe)")
        {

            var row = (int)((ComboBox)sender).Tag;
            Grid.SetRow(txt, row);
            Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);
            txt.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
            grid_typeFixture.Children.Add(txt);
        }
        else
           grid_typeFixture.Children.Remove(txt);
    }
```

Comment: what if it comes to else part directly without creating?

Comment: if i change the selected value to Not equal to "Other(Describe)" in ComboBox, its not removing the created Textbox.. i want it in run time

Comment: what is the created textbox name?

Comment: i have code to creating Combox and textbox dynamically. if i click a button, it will create combobox and textbox one by one. i have already done that. I am adding new textbox to the Grid row for the selected combobox value. I am able to create textbox for the selected row. but if i change the selected value, it will not remove the textbox in the correcponding row

Comment: you are not creating if you select  other than Other (describe). it directly comes to the else part

Comment: yep, it means, if i already created any textbox for any row using the combobox selected item.. If i change the combobox item, i want to delete the textbox in runtime.

Comment: then check my answer! you need to check for a null inside the else part, otherwise you will get an error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a name to your TextBox while creating, you can use [`RegisterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.registername.aspx),

```
        txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        txt.Name = "DynamicLine" + i;
        RegisterName(txt.Name, txt);
        Grid.SetRow(txt, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(txt, 2);
        grid_typeFixture.Children.Add(txt);
```

And you can remove like this, using [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
     txt = (TextBox)grid_typeFixture.FindName("lbl_DynamicLine" + row);
     if (txt != null)
            {
                UnregisterName(txt.Name); 
                grid_typeFixture.Children.Remove(txt);
            }
```

Comment: please check the creation part , you need tor register the name, also check your mail

Comment: If i change the ComboItem value to !=Other(Describe), it will remove the textbox. but if i again check the value=Other(Describe), it shows the error on the, RegisterName(txt.Name, txt). I am unable to create textbox for the row. now the error in reverse order.!

Comment: @RajDeInno You need to call Unregistername while removing, please check the modified code! mark it as an answer if it has helepd you

Comment: Buddy, if i select any other Item except "Other (Describe)", its directly comes to else part and looking for UnregisteredName. for the first time checking, we don't have Registered name to Unregister.!

Comment: @RajDeInno add a null check like above!

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk of setting the Textbox names dynamically if it doesn't follow the namming rules (Example : Textbox name can not have white space), Instead you can use "Tag" property of the textbox while creating and search it whenever want to remove it.